# JIRA - Java API or REST API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

i am actually analyzing JIRA for my company regarding the functionalities and the different APIs. At the Atlassian Homepage i found two official provided APIs (JAVA API or JIRA REST API).

My further intentions are to program an interface between my stand-alone application and JIRA. The idea is for instance to control the user-management (add, delete, modify user, etc.), project-management (create project, delete, etc.) and other things from this application. Therefore i need a way to interact with JIRA. 
Normally i would avoid the REST API and prefer the JAVA API, because other interfaces are even managed by the JAVA API, but i can't find any examples for connecting, adding or modifying workItems in JIRA. I have just found the java api documentation.

   https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/java-api-policy-for-jira

Would you suggest only the JAVA REST API or are there any good examples for the JAVA API?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. The Java API is mostly used to build Jira plugins, while the REST API is used when you want to integrate external applications.

In your case the normal choice would be the REST API.

Comment: Thank you! I think REST will be the solution for me.

Nevertheless, do you know any examples for the pure java api?

Comment: The documentation is seriously lacking, if not missing altogether. I couldn't find anything on the official website, apart from the class docs https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/server/ and some posts from other people asking for examples and not being replied to. However, i found this page with some examples http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.issuetabpanel.IssueAction

Comment: I'll keep looking, and i'll post here if i find something else